# Install-Package : The remote name could not be resolved: 'packages.nuget.org'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-extensions

For no reason, I have been getting this error message for a week or so;

> PM> Install-Package Elmah Install-Package : The remote name could not
>   be resolved: 'packages.nuget.org' At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Elmah
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.Net.WebException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

when I navigate to the link in my browser, I see the proper ODATA Nuget Feed.

Checked the feed's fwlink url, it works fine on the browser as well;

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669

I tried the Manage Nuget Packages dialog box, the same error there.

BTW, my internal nuget servers works fine.

Can u help me on this? what blocks me to get to packages.nuget.org?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you update to NuGet 1.4. I had a similar error while using 1.0 and updated worked for me.

Comment: no, I am using v1.4.20701.9038.

Comment: then you have definitely changed the firewall settings for NuGet. If you're using Windows Firewall, make an exception for NuGet. If you're behind a corporate firewall, make sure that the proper port is open.

Comment: no I am certainly not behind the corporate firewall, I checked that. weird thing happened after I posted this question, suddenly it resolved packages.nuget.org. I don't know what caused that but it is weird to work suddenly without any intervention.