# Several errors in cross-platform application in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have a serious problem with creating cross-platform applications.

When I'm trying to create the project the following error displayed:
[image: Error list]

How to fix these issues?

Comment: Have you tried restoring your nuget packages, delete all your bin and obj directories, closing and reopen visual studio and rebuild

Comment: Anyone answering this question might consider that the information will only be useful to the OP, as there is no information that can be searched for in this question. Please don't post important information as images. Images should ***supplement*** a well formed question. Take the images away and the question should still be answerable. Also, there's no code. All in all, a really bad question.

Comment: Rightclick solution, click restore nuget packages

Comment: It seems that `api.nuget.org` cannot be resolved on this machine. Talk to your network administrators and check DNS settings.

Comment: So, you mean it's a network issue? @LexLi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303466/the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved-api-nuget-org)

Comment: @RasoolAhmed can you prove it is not?

Comment: I'm struggling with this issue about a month. I called the network administrator and they said the internet connection has no problem.

Comment: When you load https://api.nuget.org/ in a web browser, what are the contents shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem,

The problem is with UWP project. This project is trying to restore packages from api.nuget.org but failed every time.

I removed this project from the solution and the entire solution is working perfectly now.

Note: UWP project can work separately, but it can't work with Android and iOS projects. I still don't know what the problem is, I reported this issue to Visual Studio report center.
But for now, I need only Android and iOS projects.